# django - Get the set of objects from Many To One relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

Please have a look at these models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, default=3)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

How do I get the the set of photos for a particular album??? And how to get the **Album** from the **photo** *instance* itself?

I tried this:

```
# To get the set of photos from the user (tika) album:
>>>t = User.objects.get(username='tika')
>>>t_album = Album.objects.get(user=t)
>>>t_album 
<Album: tika_album>
>>>t_album.image_set.all()
AttributeError: 'Album' Object has no attribute 'image_set'
```

Please guide me to the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are almost there. you should be using `photo_set` instead of `image_set`

```
>>>t_album.photo_set.all()
```

i.e  the lowercase modelname with `_set`

If you want the list of photos in 1 query,

```
photos = Photo.objects.filter(album__user__username='tika')
```

Comment: One question about this: If I iterate over photo_set would I be doing a hit to the database in each iteration (since the album field in Photo model has a ForeignKey to Album)

Answer (score 26):

Even better, you can write, in `Photo`

```
album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='photos', default=3)
```

The `photos` will be the name of the reverse field from `Album` to `Photo`. If you don't define it, the reverse field will be named `photo_set`.

You then use

```
t_album.photos.all()  # only if you've defined the `related_name` argument to 'photos'
```

or

```
t_album.photo_set.all()
```