# How can I access a specific field of a queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-views, django-queryset

I have these models in my Django app:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    book_rating = models.ForeignKey('Rating', null=True)

RATE_CHOICES = zip(range(1,6), range(1,6))
class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    this_book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, choices=RATE_CHOICES)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=4000, null=True)
```

I am trying to access the Ratings of each instance of the Book model. Here is what I've tried so far in the shell:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Rating)
>>> ctype
<ContentType: rating>
>>> book_titles = ctype.model_class().objects.filter(this_book__title='My Test Book')
>>> book_titles
<QuerySet [<Rating: My Test Book - parrot987 - 3.0>, <Rating: My Test Book - 123@gmail.com - 5.0>]>
```

1. How can I access the two rating values of each object (5.0 and 3.0) without all of this other data?
2. Can this be done in such a way that I am able to average the numbers and return the final value?

Comment: you have many books and each of them has many rating by users. right? if so why you don't use a ManyToMany field? then you can get all the ratings of a book and average the rates and etc

Comment: `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Rating)` and `ctype.model_class()` is a really roundabout way of getting `Rating`, which you had already imported anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For 1. you can use ([relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)):

```
Rating.objects.filter(this_book__title='My Test Book').values('rate')
```

If you just want a flat list you can use `values_list('rate', flat=True)` instead of `values('rate')`.

For 2 ([relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)):

```
from django.db.models import Avg

Rating.objects.filter(this_book__title='My Test Book').aggregate(Avg('rate'))
```

This will return a dictionary where the key is `rate__avg` and the value is the average of the ratings.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following for Many to One fields [django - Get the set of objects from Many To One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799955/django-get-the-set-of-objects-from-many-to-one-relationship)

To access the rating, you can use a for loop and access the individual values e.g.

```
total = 0
for rating in book_titles.book_set.all()
    total += rating.rate
```

Good luck!